# CLLocationManager doesn't get called when returning from a different VC

Tags: objective-c, swift

CLLocationManager delegate doesn't get called when I return to a view from another view controller. But it works perfectly fine if the view controller loads without presenting another view controller.

For example, everytime `if defaults.objectForKey("firstTimeUser") == nil {` is called and that view controller is dismissed, CLLocationManager delegate doesn't get called.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if defaults.objectForKey("firstTimeUser") == nil {
        if let servicesController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ServicesController") as? UITableViewController {
            self.navigationController?.presentViewController(servicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        defaults.setObject("set", forKey: "firstTimeUser")
        defaults.synchronize()
    } else {
        getLocationData()
        loadNewsData()
    }   
}

func getLocationData() {
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 3000
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

I believe it has something to do with [LocationManager being called inside a class method rather than an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072447/4399243). Also tried setting LocationManager in the main_thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 3000
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
})
```

Comment: When `defaults.objectForKey("firstTimeUser") == nil` is true, you don't call `getLocationData`, and so the delegate is never set.

Comment: @michael Correct, and the code presents `servicesController`, but when I dismiss `servicesController` and return to the view controller, `getLocationData()` delegates are not called.

Comment: So do you know that `viewDidAppear` is rerunning when you dismiss the VC? For example if the VC is displayed as a popover on an iPad, the previous VC's viewDidAppear won't rerun.